# filtering out the data from the dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, dataframe

i am trying to filter out the data from the following dataframe:

[image: dataframe]

i want to parse the column Name and for each value of rows matching in type1 - i want to get the values.

so i firstly want the values of Name column in a dictionary1.
then for each value of this dictionary1 - if the value matches with the value of Type1 column as a dictionary2, get the values of the Value column as a dictionary3

can anyone help me with the python code for it?

expected output:

for each value of Name matching in Type1, fetch the Value1

Comment: please paste the dataframe in your question and dont post an image

Comment: thanks @Subhrajyoti Das for editing it.

Comment: What have you tried, exactly? We do expect some sort of effort to be put into problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can try sth like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'type1':['a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','c','c','c','d','d'],'value':['q','w','e','r','t','y','u','i','o','p','a','s','d','f']})
df.groupby('type1').agg(list).to_dict('index')

{'a': {'value': ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r']},
 'b': {'value': ['t', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o']},
 'c': {'value': ['p', 'a', 's']},
 'd': {'value': ['d', 'f']}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5417511/luigigi
I am not getting the expected output.
let me reiterate and share my datafile as well

Comment: D_Name D_ID D_Header M_ID
a 1.2.3 a 2.3.5
b 2.3.5 a 3.4.5
c 5.3.2 a 3.6.3
d 4.7.3 a 2.6.7
nan nan b 3.2.6
nan nan b 5.6.3
nan nan b 2.3.5
nan nan b 3.4.5
nan nan c 3.6.3
nan nan c 2.6.7
nan nan c 3.2.6
nan nan c 5.6.3
nan nan d 2.3.5
nan nan d 3.4.5
nan nan d 3.6.3
nan nan d 2.6.7

i dont want the nan or the null values.
for every value in the column "D_Name", i need the dictionary containing the values of "D_ID".
also, for each value of column "D_Name", if the value exists in the column "D_Header", fetch the values of colunm "M_ID" into a dictionary

Comment: @Ankit post your dataframe **formated** in your question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you data is held in **df**:

```
extracted = {}
for k in df.name:
    values = []
    for i, value in enumerate(df.type1):
        if value == k:
            values.append(df.type2[i])
    extracted[k] = values
```

You can use list comprehension to extract your data in one line:

```
{k:[df.type2[i] for i, value in enumerate(df.type1) if value==k] for k in df.name}
```

Both yield:

```
{'a': ['q', 'w', 'e', 'r'], 'b': ['t', 'y', 'u', 'i', 'o'], 'c': ['p', 'a', 's'], 'd': ['d', 'f']}
```

You can also have the values in the dict be DataFrames like this:

```
{k:df.type2[df.type1==k] for k in df.name}
```

which yields:

```
{'a': 
0    q
1    w
2    e
3    r
Name: type2, dtype: object, 
'b': 
4    t
5    y
6    u
7    i
8    o
Name: type2, dtype: object, 
'c': 
9     p
10    a
11    s
Name: type2, dtype: object, 
'd': 
12    d
13    f
Name: type2, dtype: object}
```